# Get join table id in loop of joined objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a many-to-many relationship of Alphas and Betas (to simplify) and I am looping as such:

```
<% alpha.betas.each do |beta| %>
  <p>Name: <%= beta.name %></p>
<% end %>
```

What is a good way to get the id of the `alpha_beta` join table row for each? Basically, one beta may be used several times in an alpha. The user will be submitting information against each beta of an alpha, so that information needs to be specific not just to the beta, but that instance of the beta.

```
<% alpha.betas.each do |beta| %>
  <p>Name: <%= beta.name %></p>
  <p>ID: <!-- alpha_beta.id --></p>
<% end %>
```

I'm already have my join tables and models set up per the Ruby on Rails docs and it's working perfectly. Just trying to figure out a clean way to do this.

I also have an `alpha_beta` model instantiated for my join table, so it's easy to get the id from a controller...within a loop from my view is another thing, though.

Models:

```
class Alpha_beta < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :alpha
  belongs_to :beta
end

class Beta < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :alpha_betas
  has_many :alphas, :through => :alpha_betas
end

class Alpha < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :alpha_betas
  has_many :betas, :through => :alpha_betas
end
```

Comment: Why this one is relating to angularjs?

Comment: Sorry, am using angular in this project, but I didn't realize it isn't in use on this particular component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not this?

```
<% Alpha_Beta.all.each do |ab| %>
  <p>Name: <%= ab.beta.name %></p>
  <p>ID: <%= ab.id %></p>
<% end %>
```

Loop the `alpha_betas`, then you have all of your attributes.

Comment: I thought this wouldn't work. If, in my model, an ``alpha_beta`` belongs_to_many ``betas``, I assumed I could ask for ``beta.alpha_beta`` but not ``alpha_beta.beta``

Comment: It's going to take a lot of refactoring to organize it this way. I didn't want to go down that [enormous] rabbit hole if this is a hunch.

Comment: Actually, I think I had my rails console test syntax wrong. I'll refactor now. Thanks.

Comment: This is correct, thanks. In case anyone else is having difficulties with this. Make sure you have a model for the join table itself and you have your models set up as I have above.